# SMTP not connected with python ftplib

Tags: python-2.7, smtp

i want to transfer file from my local to another server with FTP.

I have use this code

```
myHostname = "ftphost.com"
myUsername = "OPpsolsS45"
myPassword = "HIO5dsafS" 

from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftp=FTP_TLS()
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.connect('myHostname', 22)

ftp.sendcmd(myUsername)
ftp.sendcmd(myPassword)
ftp.dir()
ftp.close()



 File "f_t_p.py", line 9, in <module>
    ftp.connect('myHostname', 22)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

but i am geting this error

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code you are using (eg. you cut and pasted, instead of retyping)...

You need to take a look at your connection line.

ftp.connect('myHostname', 22)

You're passing in a string literal, and not the variable.